# How do I remove(drop) page number of blank pages between chapters added by two-sided mode?

Tags: latex, document-class

I want to keep the blank pages that added using two-side mode, however I want drop those pages from numbering. Using `\clearpage` and `\thispagestyle{empty}` at end of chapters to force blank pages manually when using one-side mode do not do that either. I meant using those commands altogether just give plain pages but yet considered in numbering.

Comment: So you still want the blank pages, but without the numbering in the bottom. But also, you want those removed from the numbering altogether? So, page 11 (odd), blank page (even), page 13 (odd) should turn into page 11 (odd), blank page, page 12 (even)?

Comment: For more clarification, in fact I don't understand what is the benefit of using odd/even pages, I thought two-sided mode is using to keep safe margins right/left safe enough for printing the thesis. So, If i understand correctly, based on you example I want them: page 11 (normal text page, probably is an end of a chapter), blank page (empty), page 12 (normal text page, probably is a beginning of a chapter is numbered as 12) and so on. I wish you got it.

Comment: Well, a two-side document *always* prints the start of the chapter on an odd page, since that will be a recto page, with the facing (verso) side blank. As you mention, recto (odd) and verso (even) pages also may have different margins, so just suggesting a page numbering change would be a lot of work to keep the margins straight. Why not remove the `twoside` mode?

Comment: I just got it. Does `oneside` will keep safe margins. All what I wanted to avoid numbering blank pages in the thesis which gives not real number of pages at last. If this could be done by `oneside`, so I will use it.

Comment: That's it. `oneside` should not insert blank pages between major sectional units (like `\part` or `\chapter`).

Answer (score 0):

Import the `afterpage` package using:

```
\usepackage{afterpage}
```

If you want a totally blank page that doesn't add to the page number, use:

```
\afterpage{\null
           \thispagestyle{empty}
           \addtocounter{page}{-1}
           \newpage}
```

If you want a blank page that adds to the page counter, remove `\addtocounter{page}{-1}`